# Dismiss View when Label is pressed in TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, dismiss

i have a label with a TapGesture in a table view cell that should dismiss the view controller, which is embedded in a Navigation controller, if its pressed.

Normally I would do it like that:

`_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

OR

`self.dismiss(animated: true)`

But this is not working inside the table view cell class.

Would be great if someone could help me!

Comment: Is your callback being called? Is your label "User interaction Enabled"? Default for UILabel is false.

Comment: This will not work in table view cell class but in view controller class, where that table view cell is used.

Comment: "this is not working" is really unhelpful. What is happening? Is the code being called? (Set a breakpoint.) What is the full method your gesture recognizer calls?

Comment: Please show the code that implements the gesture recognizer

Answer (score 0):

For it to work you should pass that obligation to the viewController which is managing your tableView. So above your tableViewCell class declare a protocol with a function which the delegate (In this case the ViewController which is holding your tableView) should implement when called. So when a delegate gets called inside a ViewController dismiss the ViewController if it was modally presented and pop it if it was pushed, so one of the methods you mentioned above should work. If you  Don't know how custom protocols work, try reading this article https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1